# How to test SOAP web-service without SOAP UI?

Tags: java, testing, soap, junit, jax-ws

Collegues, I have a test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class ServiceIFTest {


@Autowired
ServiceIF ServiceIF; /*this is web service endpoint bean */

    @Test
    public void createMonIntBalTranDoc() {
        TranDocReq parameter = new TranDocReq();
        /*set variables*/
        CreateTranDocRes tranDoc = serviceIF.createTranDoc(parameter);
        assertNotEquals(java.util.Optional.ofNullable(tranDoc.getId()), 0);

    }
}
```

it is a simple Junit test where I check class field value.

But I need to do an integration test, I would like to check an XML which service will return to the client.
At the current moment if found a quite old article https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/tutorials/ws-soa-autotest2/ws-soa-autotest2.html
where the author recommends writing client etc...

So the question is how to test integration between soap web service and client from Java project?
In other words, I need to check the XML response returned by my web service.

P.s. Some years ago I did it with SOAP UI and groovy. Also, I tried to use `jaxbToString` converter, but it cut namespaces.

Comment: How to test SOAP web-service without SOAP UI? Use Postman :)

Comment: Thank you, but i need to test it from project (test class) without using any external tools.